# why my component is not re-rendering in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

So i was trying to change my component when state (in my case submitted) is  changed. when ever i update the state normally (not inside http get)it will changed my component properly but when i do the same thing inside http get call state is updated but my component will not change.Please give any suggestions for solving this problem. Thanks in advance.... :)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Panel, Grid, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap';
import styles from './Panels.scss';
import Card from '../Card/Card.js';
import PanelForm from '../PanelForm/PanelForm';
import PanelFormData from '../PanelFormData/PanelFormData';
import http from 'axios';
export default class Panels extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
      submitted:0,
      allocatedBudgetData:this.props.allocatedBudgetData
    }
    this.updateStateForm=this.updateStateForm.bind(this);
  }

  //this function is called by another component and update the state
  updateStateForm(){
    http.get('./static/PanelReportDataFilled.json')
      .then((response) => {
      var submitted=this.state.submitted==0?1:0;
      console.log('inside http method',submitted);
      this.setState({
        allocatedBudgetData:response.data,
        submitted:submitted
      });

    })

  }
     render() {
    console.log('inside render state is ',this.state.submitted); 

    const panelFormInput=(<PanelForm formState={this.state.submitted} formType={this.updateStateForm} role={this.props.role} allocatedBudgetData={this.state.allocatedBudgetData}></PanelForm>);
    return(
      <Panel header={this.props.title} bsStyle="primary" className={styles['panels']}>
        <Grid>
          <Row className="show-grid">
            <Col sm={5} md={8}>
              <div style={{height: "auto"}}>
                <Card renderchild={panelFormInput} borderRadius={4}/>
              </div>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Grid>
      </Panel>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you do as @harkirat suggests and rename http to axios. Also I suggest you add a catch to your axios call to ensure an error is not being thrown and swallowed up by react. Finally, you may want to post your "Card" jsx so we can take a look that there are no typos there preventing the call to updateStateForm.

Comment: @Paulstoner  the thing is when ever i am changing the state inside of updateStateform() and commented the http get call its working fine. but when i do it inside of then it changed the state but not changing the component. So there will be issue with card .

Comment: my apologies. I'm too new to react to be of anymore help. What I have learned thus for is that the component should update as state changes. I have learned the hard way that if the component does not update then there is some issue with how the change in state is being passed down to the child.

Comment: @paulstoner the same i also learnt but it's not updating from inside of http get method.

Comment: are you simply attempting to mock an API to read the contents of the json file?

Comment: @PaulStoner yes! you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your api call is not taking place because of  `import http from axios`.

This is not the way you use axios. It should be as

`import axios from 'axios'`

Your API should be something like

```
axios.get('./static/PanelReportDataFilled.json')
      .then((response) => {
      var submitted=this.state.submitted==0?1:0;
      console.log('inside http method',submitted);
      this.setState({
        allocatedBudgetData:response.data,
        submitted:submitted
      });

    })
```

Please read more about axios [here](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios)

Comment: it doesn't matter what  variable name you assigned to your import in my case it's http in your case it's axios. and i already added 'axios' in my question . please take a look. BTW thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

By moving this.setState({}); into the http.get, the **this** keyword now references the parent's function, hence referencing the http object.

Try:

```
updateStateForm(){
    var _self = this;
    http.get('./static/PanelReportDataFilled.json')
      .then((response) => {
      var submitted=this.state.submitted==0?1:0;
      console.log('inside http method',submitted);
      _self.setState({
        allocatedBudgetData:response.data,
        submitted:submitted
      });
    })
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Rethinking my initial response, I think the following may be a better solution.

Setup a mock API as follows, i.e. reportDataApi.js:

```
"use strict";

const reportData = [/* mock out your data here*/
  ]

class ReportDataApi {
  static getReportData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeOut(() => {
        resolve(Object.assign([], reportData));
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}

export default ReportDataApi;
```

Then in your controller component (I refactored the code you posted):

```
...
import reportDataApi from './static/ReportDataApi'; <- reference to mock API js file

export default class Panels extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      submitted: 0,
      allocatedBudgetData: this.props.allocatedBudgetData
    }
    this.updateStateForm = this
      .updateStateForm
      .bind(this);
  }

  //this function is called by another component and update the state
  updateStateForm() {
    var submitted = this.state.submitted === 0 ? 1 : 0;
    console.log('inside http method', submitted);
    this.setState({allocatedBudgetData: reportDataApi.getReportData, submitted: submitted});                            ^^^ Call to mock API
  }
     ...
    )
  }
}
```

Hopefully, this will get you over that hump. Good Luck

Comment: but in future i need to add an api end point so i think above solution will work if you are reading data from locally not from api .

Comment: the design pattern I laid out above should easily allow for a switch to an actual data endpoint. I have used this pattern several times without fail

Comment: Apologies. But could you explain the reason for the down vote? I really am interested in expanding my capabilites

Comment: There's no need to introduce two additional technologies, `redux` and `react-redux` to mock an API call.

Comment: @lux Accepted. I appreciate your candor and feedback. This was simply an example I provided from my own learning and experience. I will do better to provide more acceptable answers.